# Automatic onload from a slider page in Wordpress to sub content page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onload

I got a WordPress start page which got 3 slides, after the 3 slides it should load automatically the next content (subpage). So I don't know how do it - some onload functions in the functions.php or something else?

That's the running order for the pages:

1. Home (3 Slides with Picture & Logo Animations)
2. Strategy (Content Page)
3. Change Management
4. Investor Search
5. About
6. Contact

I tried with a redirect - that does not work! and I was searching for some onload functions, but that ones I find - where only for get on a section but on the same page.

Comment: which slider are you using ? did you see if you can have some action with this slider ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: just using the origin page builder slider - how i just tried out with the plugin "Shortcode Redirect"  - on the full width pages entered similar code "[redirect url='http://tothenextsite.com' sec='5']"...